# How to build a Python package with dependency on other custom python Package?

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

I have a Python project and I want to publish it to `Pypi`. Let's call it `Package_main`.
I used some local/private/custom Python packages (`Package_1` and `Package_2`) in `Package_main`.

In `Package_main`:

```
import Numpy, matplotlib     # import public packages
import Package_1, Package_2  # import private/local/custom packages
```

**Note:**
I installed Numpy and matplotlib by command `pip install Numpy, matplotlib`.
I installed `Package_1` and `Package_2` by command `python setup.py develop` in the corresponding directory. Because the two packages have not been built and published to `Pypi` yet.

I have tried to build `Package_main` and publish it to `Pypi`. But I found after I downloaded `Package_main` in a new environment and use it, error shows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Package_1
```

It means that my local `Package_1` and `Package_2` are not included into the `Package_main`.

I am willing to publich `Package_main` along with `Package_1` and `Package_2`. Can you tell me how to do it? (I know one method is to publich `Package_1` and `Package_2` seperately to `Pypi` and then use them the same way as how I use `Numpy`, but I think this method seems not elegant, do you have any other solutions?)

Answer (score 0):

A package in python would ideally need an `__init__.py` file to qualify as a package. Given that you need to pull data under the same root, there needs to be an `__init__.py` at your root that holds all of the necessary imports to your files.